# Desiging restful API for user resource

Tags: php, angularjs, api, rest

I am designing a restful API by using Laravel & AngularJS. I know the basic of restful API, but having trouble to figure out what will be the best way to design it for **user** resource.

Let's guess, user can have his profile & can update profile. So, the URL should be something like this:

1. For User Profile View: `www.example.com/users/{id}`
2. For User Profile Update: `www.example.com/users/{id}/edit`

but these URLs look bad. The pretty URLs are:

1. For User Profile View: `www.example.com/profile`
2. For User Profile Update: `www.example.com/profile/edit`

OR

1. For User Profile View: `www.example.com/{username}`
2. For User Profile Update: `www.example.com/{username}/edit`

My question is, if I use the last two pretty URLs, will it break the restful API principle? And which is the most appropriate way of designing API for **user** resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should get the advantage of using `HTTP` verbs in `RESTFUL` api's which would make your url's more readable such:

```
`GET www.example.com/users/{id}` for profile retrieval
`PUT www.example.com/users/{id}` for profile update
```

You can review this blog for more information [HTTP Verbs](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using the HTTP verbs. But, I am not sure, only HTTP verbs define REST or the URL part or both.

Comment: @Anindya will this is up to your design, but for me the best practice is to influence the meaning of the `HTTP` verbs to define the meaning of the operation related to the resource, in this way you will minimize the explanation in the url, also always avoid using verbs in the endpoints always use nouns to provide a better api check this post [restful_api_design_nouns_are_good_verbs_are_bad](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_nouns_are_good_verbs_are_bad)